# makefile: path issue under windows

Tags: windows, makefile

I'n new to make and the makefiles and got a - probably - very simple problem.

I've startd to work through the [XUL School tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School) and I'm stuck when It came to the point where you start to use the komodo editor, cygwin and make.

My actual problem is the install part if the makefile script.
I'll condense the makefile script to a minimal size that shows the problem:

```
...
# The target location of the build and build files.
bin_dir := ../bin
...
# The temporary location where the extension tree will be copied and built.
build_dir := $(bin_dir)/build
...# The sources for the XPI file.
xpi_built := install.rdf \
             chrome.manifest \
             $(wildcard content/*.js) \
             $(wildcard content/*.xul) \
             $(wildcard content/*.xml) \
             $(wildcard content/*.css) \
             $(wildcard skin/*.css) \
             $(wildcard skin/*.png) \
             $(wildcard locale/*/*.dtd) \
             $(wildcard locale/*/*.properties)
...
.PHONY: install
install: $(build_dir) $(xpi_built)
    @echo "Installing in profile folder: $(profile_location)"
    @cp -Rf $(build_dir)/* $(profile_location)
    @echo "Installing in profile folder. Done!"
...
```

The problem is here:

.PHONY: install
install: $(build_dir) $(xpi_built)

As far as I understood this script, this line of code should copy all files mentioned in xpi_built to the build_dir folder.
The build_dir folder should be relative to the folder where the makefile is in.

The problem is that the build folder remains empty after running the script (running the command 'bash -c "export OSTYPE; make install"' from komodo)

When I put any files into the build folder manually, they are successfully copied to the $(profile_location), meaning that the command "@cp -Rf $(build_dir)/* $(profile_location)" works fine.

So in short words my question is: 
Why are the files from  $(xpi_built) aren't copied into the $(build_dir) folder?

EDIT: [Link to the complete Makefile](http://pastebin.com/SDwx63cu)

Answer (score 1):

```
.PHONY: install
install: $(build_dir) $(xpi_built)
    @echo "Installing in profile folder: $(profile_location)"
    @cp -Rf $(build_dir)/* $(profile_location)
    @echo "Installing in profile folder. Done!"
```

You appear not to understand the meaning of these lines.

The first line is a directive to `make`. It tells `make` that `install` is a phony target, i.e.
`install` is not a *file*, it's just a name for some task that `make` may do, so you can invoke
`make install` and `make` will do that task. A phony target is "always out-of-date".

The next line is a rule. It says that the phony target `install` is dependent on whatever list of prerequisites `$(build_dir)` expands to, and also
on whatever list of prerequisites `$(xpi_built)` expands to. So to make the phony target `install`, `make`
will first have to make each thing `x` in those combined lists, if `x` doesn't exist or is
out of date with respect to its own prerequisites.

You say you believe that the rule instructs `make` to copy all `$(xpi_built)` files to `$(build_dir)`. I'm afraid
it does nothing of the kind. A rule is not a command. It just expresses the dependency between targets and their
prerequisites.

The next three lines, the indented ones, are a recipe. Each line of a recipe is a command that `make` will execute
if the target of the recipe is out-of-date. The `@` prefix of each command in the recipe instructs `make` not
to echo the command itself, just do it.

The first and last commands of the recipe print obvious messages on the console. The second command copies
files and subdirectories, recursively and forcibly, from the path(s) that `$(build_dir)/*` expands to into the directory that
`$(profile_location)` expands to. (*Note that the condensed makefile you have posted assigns no value to* `$(profile_location)`)

There is no command in the `install` recipe that copies `$(xpi_built)` into `$(build_dir)`, and there is no
target on which `install` depends that has a recipe in which this is done. So it isn't done.

If you want it to be done in the `install` recipe, then add the appropriate copy command to the recipe:

```
install: $(build_dir) $(xpi_built)
    @echo "Installing in profile folder: $(profile_location)"
    @cp -Rf $(xpi_built) $(build_dir)
    @cp -Rf $(build_dir)/* $(profile_location)
    @echo "Installing in profile folder. Done!"
```

It's unclear to me however, from the makefile as posted, why the `$(xpi_built)` files should be copied into `$(build_dir)`
merely in order to copy them again from there into `$(profile_location)`, rather than just copy them directly into
`$(profile_location)`. There may be some reason among the details you have omitted.

Under cygwin, I guess you are using GNU `make`. I recommend you to study the [introductory documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Introduction)

If you are giving us a condensed version of a makefile supplied to you as *correct*, there may be a bug in it in the parts you have omitted, or a typo in those parts if it came off a webpage; or you may have introduced a bug by editing it.

**Continued with sight of the complete makefile**

The makefile you have linked to contains no target that creates or populates the directory to which `$(build_dir)` expands. The comment preceding the `install` target:

> This builds everything except for the actual XPI, and then it copies it to the
>   specified profile directory, allowing a quick update that requires no install.

is false if "builds everything" is interpreted as meaning that it populates
`$(build_dir)`.

This comment would not even be true if the makefile contained a rule with `$(build_dir)` as its target and a recipe that ensured that `$(build_dir)` existed and was populated with the up-to-date things it is supposed to contain. In that case, the dependency of `install` upon `$(build_dir)` would cause `make install` to populate `$(build_dir)` if `$(build_dir)` did not exist. But it would not do so if `$(build_dir)` *did* exist, regardless of whether its
contents were the right up-to-date things. And `$(build_dir)` is removed, with this makefile, only by explicitly invoking `make clean`.

Either the tutorial material you are studying is bunk - stranger things have
happened - or this makefile belongs in some bigger picture you haven't
grasped (and anyway, is misleadingly commented).

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks a lot for your patient answer. I've added a link to the complete Makefile of the project. Could you explain to me at which part of the script the build folder gets filled files? Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your further investigation of the Makefile. Since the tutorial is for absolute newbies, I assumed one is supplied with complete and tested learning materials, which doesn't seem to be the case. At least I know now that I'm not complete stupid, so I've "only" wasted several hours to get it...Thanks for your time!